# Files from a connected source (Google Drive) do not show up in Community

Tags: community, lightning-community, files, files-connect

We set up Files Connect for Google Drive in our org. Internal Users when logged in community can see files in Connected Sources:

[image]

Community Users (License: Customer Community Plus) get an error when trying to open this list:

> "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help
>   or to request access."

and

> "This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience. To see this
>   list view, use Salesforce Classic or switch to another list view."

[image]

The community user's profile has set the "Files Connect Cloud" system permission to True. The File Sharing mode in Files Connect Settings is set to Reference.

We use a [Files List](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_files_list.htm&type=5) standard component to show files in community.

Why can't community users access files from external sources?

Comment: Does a community user has an access to the External Data source?

Comment: Yes, community users can access external data sources.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable Salesforce Files Connect (Copy/Reference)
2. Create a Permission Sets and Assign to users

   1. Files Connect Cloud
   2. External Data Source Access (If Per User)
   3. Google Developers Console

      1. Project
      2. Configure OAuth consent screen
         a) Credentials > OAuth 2.0 Client
         b) Get Client ID and Client secret
         c) Add Authorized JavaScript origins
         d) Add Authorized redirect URIs ( Callback URL from SF)
3. Create an Authentication Provider for Google Drive 
   1.  Add Consumer Key (from Google)
   2.  Add Consumer Secret (from Google)
   3.  Add Scopes
   4.  Add Authorize / Token Endpoints
4. Define an External Data Source for Google Drive

   1. Type = Files Connect: Google Drive
   2. Identity Type = Named Principal / Per User
   3. Authentication Provider (created during step # 4)
5. Under Profile, External Object Permissions should be given
6. External Object’s Deployment Status = Deployed
7. Create a Tab for the External Object.